# Relatório no JasperStudio com subReports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Preciso criar um relatório com duas `Querys` distintas no `JasperStudio`, para isso pesquisei e vi que a melhor forma para fazer isso seria via sub relatórios porém mesmo fazendo exatamente igual a algumas vídeo aulas que encontrei no eu sempre travo no mesmo erro:

[image: printscreen com as telas do JasperStudio com um alet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como está o nome do seu subreport? Pelo erro ele não está sendo encontrado. Verifique se criou um novo report (que será o subreport) com esse nome: "subreport". Depois de criado, é preciso copilar ele, para poder ger o arquivo ".jasper".

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda pedro, era justamente esse o problema, faltava compilar o subReport, eu já tinha encontrado essa resposta em outro fórum só não havia conseguido vir aqui e  responder minha pergunta